# Why does return work like break in this Bash function when piping from cat to a while loop?

Tags: bash

I have a function calling another, with unexpected results:

```
#!/bin/bash

function doSomething() {
    callee
    echo $?
    echo "It should go here!"
}

function callee() {
    cat line.txt | while read ln
    do
        echo $ln
        if [ 1 ] ;then
            { echo "This is callee" &&
            return 2; }
        fi  
    done
    echo "It should not go here!"
}


doSomething
```

Here is the result:

```
aa
This is callee
It should not go here!
0
It should go here!
```

Why does `return` act like `break` here? I want it to exit the `callee` function, not just break the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you are using a pipe into a `while` loop, which runs in a subshell (in Bash).  You are returning from the subshell, not the function.  Try this:

```
function callee() { 
    while read ln 
    do 
        echo $ln 
        if [ 1 ] ;then 
            echo "This is callee" 
            return 2;   
        fi   
    done  < line.txt
    echo "It should not go to here!" 
}
```

Kill the cat!

Comment: Another reason for the OP to avoid the UUOC (Useless Use of Cat) Award.

Answer (score 1):

The `while` executes in a subshell (because of the pipe), so anything you do will only have effect within that shell. You can't, for instance, change values of variables in the containing scope.

Answer (score -1):

You should use

```
exit [number as status]
```

for example

```
exit 0
```

or just

```
exit
```

The exit command terminates a script. It can also return a value, which is available to the script's parent process.

Comment: `exit` will still only exit from the subshell in this case, returning control to the shell running the `while` loop.